# SSIS CSV export: comma within fields in comma delimited file

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Im trying to export a CSV file (fields delimited by ',') and few of the columns happen to have , within them. Such fields, if they happen to have , within them should be enclosed within " " and sent out. I tried using " as text qualifier in the export package but it encloses each and every field value with quotes ballooning the file size.

Can someone help here?

Comment: did you considered using pipe | as delimiter. you may avoid text qualifier this way

Comment: through a dtsx package using a 'flat file connection' setting column delimiter as ,     text qualifier as "              Im being forced to use , as column delimiter and cant change it to | etc